# Xcode 6 + OS X Server 10.10 failing initial push to server

Tags: xcode, macos, git, xcode6, osx-server

I fresh installed OS X Server 10.10 on my iMac the other day. In the Xcode service settings, I have set repositories to be accessed over https and to be able to be created by logged in users. From my laptop, I'm able to add my server to the Xcode 6 account preferences and authenticate successfully. However, when I create a new project and select my server for where I want to create a git repository, it creates the project, but fails when it attempts to push to the server for the first time. It shows the error: "Unable to connect to remote repository". This behavior is the same on both the laptop and the iMac (Server). The weird thing is that when I look at the Xcode Service manager in the OS X Manager app, it shows the repositories as being created, but with no content.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!